# What disposition means in the context of registering clinical studies?

Tags: pharmacology, clinical-trial

I was diving into the [AACT database](https://www.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/aact-database), and in the `studies` table I had noticed some columns containing the term *disposition* such as:

- `disposition_first_submitted_date`
- `disposition_first_submitted_qc_date` (qc means quality control)
- `disposition_first_posted_date`
- `disposition_first_posted_date_type`

and I do not know what disposition means in this context.

## Additional information

The AACT database contains the same data as [ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/), but in a relational databse, so it is a database of all clinical trials made in the US, but also has international studies.

Every row in the `studies` table represents a clinical study.

Here is the first 5 rows where the `disposition_first_submitted_date` is not null, alongside the header:

```
|nct_id                                                                                              |nlm_download_date_description                                                                       |study_first_submitted_date|results_first_submitted_date|disposition_first_submitted_date|last_update_submitted_date|study_first_submitted_qc_date|study_first_posted_date|study_first_posted_date_type                                                                        |results_first_submitted_qc_date|results_first_posted_date|results_first_posted_date_type                                                                      |disposition_first_submitted_qc_date|disposition_first_posted_date|disposition_first_posted_date_type                                                                  |last_update_submitted_qc_date|last_update_posted_date|last_update_posted_date_type                                                                        |start_month_year                                                                                    |start_date_type                                                                                     |start_date|verification_month_year                                                                             |verification_date|completion_month_year                                                                               |completion_date_type                                                                                |completion_date|primary_completion_month_year                                                                       |primary_completion_date_type                                                                        |primary_completion_date|target_duration                                                                                     |study_type                                                                                          |acronym                                                                                             |baseline_population                                                                                 |brief_title                                                                                         |official_title                                                                                      |overall_status                                                                                      |last_known_status                                                                                   |phase                                                                                               |enrollment |enrollment_type                                                                                     |source                                                                                              |limitations_and_caveats                                                                             |number_of_arms|number_of_groups|why_stopped                                                                                         |has_expanded_access|expanded_access_type_individual|expanded_access_type_intermediate|expanded_access_type_treatment|has_dmc|is_fda_regulated_drug|is_fda_regulated_device|is_unapproved_device|is_ppsd|is_us_export|biospec_retention                                                                                   |biospec_description                                                                                 |ipd_time_frame                                                                                      |ipd_access_criteria                                                                                 |ipd_url                                                                                             |plan_to_share_ipd                                                                                   |plan_to_share_ipd_description                                                                       |created_at         |updated_at         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|----------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------------|------------------------------|-------|---------------------|-----------------------|--------------------|-------|------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|NCT00684515                                                                                         |ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on February 25, 2020                                         |2008-05-22                |2014-05-09                  |2008-10-09                      |2018-08-22                |2008-05-22                   |2008-05-26             |Estimate                                                                                            |2014-07-28                     |2014-07-29               |Estimate                                                                                            |2009-10-21                         |2009-10-22                   |Estimate                                                                                            |2018-08-22                   |2018-09-21             |Actual                                                                                              |September 21, 2006                                                                                  |Actual                                                                                              |2006-09-21|August 2018                                                                                         |2018-08-31       |November 8, 2007                                                                                    |Actual                                                                                              |2007-11-08     |November 8, 2007                                                                                    |Actual                                                                                              |2007-11-08             |                                                                                                    |Interventional                                                                                      |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |Trial to Assess the Safety of Vorapaxar in Japanese Subjects With Cerebral Infarction (P05005; MK-53|Phase II Study of SCH 530348 in Subjects With Cerebral Infarction                                   |Completed                                                                                           |                                                                                                    |Phase 2                                                                                             |90         |Actual                                                                                              |Merck Sharp & Dohme Corp.                                                                           |                                                                                                    |3             |                |                                                                                                    |false              |                               |                                 |                              |true   |                     |                       |                    |       |            |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |http://engagezone.msd.com/ds_documentation.php                                                      |Yes                                                                                                 |https://www.merck.com/clinical-trials/pdf/ProcedureAccessClinicalTrialData.pdf                      |2020-02-26 08:06:42|2020-02-26 08:06:42|
|NCT00684203                                                                                         |ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on February 25, 2020                                         |2008-05-22                |2014-05-09                  |2008-10-09                      |2017-03-31                |2008-05-22                   |2008-05-26             |Estimate                                                                                            |2014-07-28                     |2014-08-15               |Estimate                                                                                            |2009-10-21                         |2009-10-22                   |Estimate                                                                                            |2017-03-31                   |2017-05-05             |Actual                                                                                              |December 1, 2006                                                                                    |Actual                                                                                              |2006-12-01|March 2017                                                                                          |2017-03-31       |October 1, 2007                                                                                     |Actual                                                                                              |2007-10-01     |October 1, 2007                                                                                     |Actual                                                                                              |2007-10-01             |                                                                                                    |Interventional                                                                                      |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |Trial to Assess the Safety and Effects of Vorapaxar in Japanese Subjects With Acute Coronary Syndrom|Phase II Study of SCH 530348 in Subjects With Acute Coronary Syndrome                               |Completed                                                                                           |                                                                                                    |Phase 2                                                                                             |120        |Actual                                                                                              |Merck Sharp & Dohme Corp.                                                                           |                                                                                                    |5             |                |                                                                                                    |false              |                               |                                 |                              |true   |                     |                       |                    |       |            |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |2020-02-26 08:06:46|2020-02-26 08:06:46|
|NCT00452426                                                                                         |ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on February 25, 2020                                         |2007-03-26                |2010-10-06                  |2008-10-16                      |2010-12-30                |2007-03-26                   |2007-03-27             |Estimate                                                                                            |2010-12-30                     |2011-01-25               |Estimate                                                                                            |2008-10-22                         |2009-10-02                   |Estimate                                                                                            |2010-12-30                   |2011-01-25             |Estimate                                                                                            |March 2007                                                                                          |                                                                                                    |2007-03-31|December 2010                                                                                       |2010-12-31       |October 2007                                                                                        |Actual                                                                                              |2007-10-31     |October 2007                                                                                        |Actual                                                                                              |2007-10-31             |                                                                                                    |Interventional                                                                                      |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |Safety and Effectiveness of a Computer-Assisted Personalized Sedation (CAPS) Device for Propofol Del|Multi-center Pivotal Clinical Trial to Compare the Safety and Effectiveness of Procedural Sedation i|Completed                                                                                           |                                                                                                    |Phase 3                                                                                             |1000       |Actual                                                                                              |Ethicon Endo-Surgery                                                                                |                                                                                                    |2             |                |                                                                                                    |false              |                               |                                 |                              |true   |                     |                       |                    |       |            |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |2020-02-26 09:15:02|2020-02-26 09:15:02|
|NCT00318214                                                                                         |ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on February 25, 2020                                         |2006-04-24                |                            |2008-12-04                      |2012-05-24                |2006-04-25                   |2006-04-26             |Estimate                                                                                            |                               |                         |                                                                                                    |2009-11-05                         |2009-11-09                   |Estimate                                                                                            |2012-05-24                   |2012-06-01             |Estimate                                                                                            |June 2006                                                                                           |                                                                                                    |2006-06-30|May 2012                                                                                            |2012-05-31       |February 2008                                                                                       |Actual                                                                                              |2008-02-29     |February 2008                                                                                       |Actual                                                                                              |2008-02-29             |                                                                                                    |Interventional                                                                                      |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |Safety and Efficacy Study of MRE0094 to Treat Large, Single or Multiple, Chronic, Neuropathic, Diabe|                                                                                                    |Terminated                                                                                          |                                                                                                    |Phase 2                                                                                             |16         |Actual                                                                                              |Pfizer                                                                                              |                                                                                                    |2             |                |The study had poor enrollment with only 16 patients randomized across 19 study centers over an¶    1|false              |                               |                                 |                              |false  |                     |                       |                    |       |            |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |2020-02-26 09:56:26|2020-02-26 09:56:26|
|NCT00312364                                                                                         |ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on February 25, 2020                                         |2006-04-06                |                            |2008-12-04                      |2012-05-24                |2006-04-06                   |2006-04-10             |Estimate                                                                                            |                               |                         |                                                                                                    |2009-11-05                         |2009-11-09                   |Estimate                                                                                            |2012-05-24                   |2012-06-01             |Estimate                                                                                            |December 2005                                                                                       |                                                                                                    |2005-12-31|May 2012                                                                                            |2012-05-31       |December 2007                                                                                       |Actual                                                                                              |2007-12-31     |December 2007                                                                                       |Actual                                                                                              |2007-12-31             |                                                                                                    |Interventional                                                                                      |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |Safety and Efficacy Study of MRE0094 to Treat Chronic, Neuropathic, Diabetic Foot Ulcers            |                                                                                                    |Completed                                                                                           |                                                                                                    |Phase 2                                                                                             |322        |Actual                                                                                              |Pfizer                                                                                              |                                                                                                    |              |                |                                                                                                    |                   |                               |                                 |                              |       |                     |                       |                    |       |            |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |                                                                                                    |2020-02-26 09:58:37|2020-02-26 09:58:37|
```

I suspect disposition in this context is not about the subjects leaving the study or the [drug interacting with the patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7569663). If I have to guess: it means the beginning of the study.